# Monitoring an FTP server folder with JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, ftp

I have Java application running on JBoss AS7 standalone. The application needs to monitor an FTP folder and pick up new files.

I'm aware of using commons-net FTPClient to connect to an FTP server, but I'm curious, is there a way to do this in the 'Enterprise Java' world? For instance, configuring an FTP server as a 'datasource' in JBoss, in a similar way to databases?

From googling, I've found things such as JBoss ESB that can be used with JBoss AS, and for which you can configure an 'FTP listener' to monitor for files - is this the way forward? (don't currently have JBoss ESB installed)

I've also come across the notion of using JCA, such as 'Oracle jca adapter for files/ftp', which mentions being compatible with JBoss, but there seems to be little info online about it. another is 'jca-for-ssh' but appears to only support outbound connections.

Am I going about this right way/googling for the right thing? Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated. thanks

Comment: For monitoring purposes, I would look at Apache Camel (http://camel.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

One would use the Java 7 [FileWatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).  This would be an efficient, event-based solution.

Another would have a Timer task that would wake up periodically, check the directory for files, process them, and then go back to sleep.

JBoss would not be my first thought, but it's possible to incorporate either one into an object of some kind and deploy on JBoss.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you gave me a lot to think about :)

I found that I couldn't get FileWatcher to work with a remote FTP folder, though it is certainly an efficient solution when working with local folders (as I understand it, it uses the underlying File System's functionality for detecting new files).

What I settled on is using an ejb scheduled method to check the FTP folder periodically, using commons-net FTPClient.

thanks again